# Why is prettier making my Handlebars HTML double quotes into single quotes?

Tags: handlebars.js, lint, prettier

I have a Vue project with a `.prettierc.js` file that looks like this

```js
module.exports = {
  semi: false,
  arrowParens: 'always',
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'es5',
}
```

So far this has worked as expected, favoring single quotes in JavaScript and TypeScript portions of the code and favoring double quotes in HTML and .vue component files.

However, I need handlebars for some templated HTML so I added the `.hbs` file. When I ran my formatting step, Prettier converted all the double quotes to single quotes in the `.hbs` file. Renaming the file to `.html` prevents this from happening, but isn't an ideal solution.

How can I get prettier to treat `.hbs` files like `.html` files and favor double quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prettier doesn't recognize `.hbs` files by default, so it doesn't make an exception to it's configured quoting rule.

Instead, the `overrides` config attribute can be used to define rule exceptions based on file name/extension.

```js
module.exports = {
  semi: false,
  arrowParens: 'always',
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'es5',

  overrides: [
    {
      files: '*.hbs',
      options: {
        singleQuote: false,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```